# Use two Mapped Types signature in one type

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces:

```js
interface A {
    a: boolean;
    b: boolean;
}

interface X  {
    x: number[];
}
```

I want to use they keys to do something like this

```js
// I need something like this
type OneType = {
    [key in  keyof A]: number;
    [key in  keyof X]: string;
}
```

but it doesn't work (tried different solutions), my current workaround is to use:

```js
type MappedA = {
    [key in keyof A]: number;
}

type MappedB = {
    [key in keyof X]: string;
}

const map: MappedA & MappedB = {
    a: 22,
    b: 223,
    x: '343'
}
```

[My current typescript playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm%20XALmQCMB7UgGwjhAG4c9iizLq6sBfLLUSWRFAA1c2PMgAeREAFcAtsWgBtALr0uWAPQbkAd1JQA1qADmyAM6VpYYKRBYwATwAOKACp6AsnCcuAJugBeTAZcRQMIB2RQZHCHUhg0ZSk5BSg1bkcXZHdSLx8IXwAhZCDRPDCIqJAYiPjkQSTzMCgTdKwEWzMwZFlvIhy8v3QAMmzPbz9i0pD8IgAmOYAaGaZkBYBmZbFJZABydYAWdd3Obi1kAElkEAgC81JZCDAACxNkCmBw5BfgM01tTIoADyN1czhQ03OYgqkWiNTiCVQjRk8mg9Ch5ViVVwsTqDSIXRaIGM6O06iwQA) Is there any other method to create working `OneType`?

Comment: `type OneType = MappedA & MappedB`?

Answer (score 2):

You could intersect the mapped types:

```
type OneType = {
    [key in keyof A]: number;
} & {
    [key in keyof X]: string;
};
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mMB6VW)